# How to remove berocket from url /shop/?filters=berocket_brand[arnold-son] in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, plugins

i want to remove berocket from url. I have tried a lot but i didn`t find any solution
currently my url is ?filters=berocket_brand[rolex]
and i want ?filters=brand[rolex]

i have tried with be rocket permalink manager but not find any solution

Comment: You'll have to modify the core files of the plugin or theme from which that param is coming.